# Fuzzy logic text transformation methodologies?

Tags: ruby, fuzzy-logic

I have a large set of data (several hundred thousand records) that are unique entries in a CSV.  These entries are essentially products that are being listed in a store from a vendor that offers these products.  The problem is that while they offer us rights to copy these verbatim or to change wording, I don't want to list them verbatim obviously since Google will slap the ranking for having "duplicate" content.  And then, also obviously, manually editing 500,000 items would take a ridiculous amount of time.

The solution, it would seem, would be to leverage fuzzy logic that would take certain phraseology and transform it to something different that would not then be penalized by Google.  I have hitherto been unable to find any real library to address this or a solid solution that addresses such a situation.

I am thinking through my own algorithms to perhaps accomplish this, but I hate to reinvent the wheel or, worse, be beaten down by the big G after a failed attempt.

My idea is to simply search for various phrases and words (sans stop words) and then essentially map those to phrases and words that can be randomly inserted that still have equivalent meaning, but enough substance to hopefully not cause a deranking situation.

A solution for `Ruby` would be optimal, but absolutely not necessary as any language can be used.

Are there any existing algorithms, theories or implementations of a similar scenario that could be used to model or solve such a scenario?